# Hibernate Cascade bidirectional relationship

Tags: hibernate, cascade

I have a Class a with:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<B> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

in Class B I have:

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_A")
    private A a;
```

When I try to persist A, like
entityManager.persist(a);

I get the following exception:

object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : B.a-> A

Comment: show the code that performs the save.. with entities set-up

Comment: This is probably caused by your Bs not having A set. You can either set A in B at the creation of B, or when calling A.add(B).

Comment: Let see the simple implemetation with OneToMany http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example.html

Comment: "save the transient instance before flushing : B.a-> A" just do what the error says to do ;)